# Providing the class for generic ArrayList within the fromJson in java gson

Tags: java, json, class, generics, gson

When I convert the `ArrayList<Student>` to json object, it gives the json as follows.

```
[{"firstName":"Namal","lastName":"Fernando"},{"firstName":"Lakmini","lastName":"Fernando"}]
```

But I'm unable to create the `ArrayList<Student>` again from the json string that I got. How can I do it. The problem is with providing the class of the generics type in fromJson method.

I tried following methods also but faild.

```
List<Student> studentsUpdated = gson.fromJson(json, new ArrayList<Student>().getClass());
List<Student> studentsUpdated = gson.fromJson(json, new ArrayList<Student>().getClass().getGenericSuperclass());
```

**Json read / write method.**

```
private void jsonUtil(){

    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    Student student1 = new Student();
    student1.setFirstName("Namal");
    student1.setLastName("Fernando");
    students.add(student1);

    Student student2 = new Student();
    student2.setFirstName("Lakmini");
    student2.setLastName("Fernando");
    students.add(student2);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(students);

    System.out.println("jsonUtil().json : " + json);

    List<Student> studentsUpdated = gson.fromJson(json, ArrayList<Student>.class); // This is the place that the error occured

}
```

**Student class :**

```
class Student{

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    String firstName = "-";
    String lastName = "-";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code :

```
 Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Student>>(){}.getType();  
 List<Student> studentsUpdated = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

instead of

```
List<Student> studentsUpdated = gson.fromJson(json, ArrayList<Student>.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use **[TypeToken](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html)** to load the json string into a custom object.

Try out this code.

```
List<Student> studentsUpdated = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Student>>(){}.getType());
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found from google docs

> If the object that your are serializing/deserializing is a
>   ParameterizedType (i.e. contains at least one type parameter and may
>   be an array) then you must use the toJson(Object, Type) or
>   fromJson(String, Type) method. Here is an example for serializing and
>   deserialing a ParameterizedType:

```
  Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
  List<String> target = new LinkedList<String>();  target.add("blah");

  Gson gson = new Gson();
 String json = gson.toJson(target, listType);
 List<String> target2 = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
```

You could try TypeToken